# Is there a way to globally disable ligatures?

Tags: fonts

Sometimes I copy text from pdf/html sources that contains ligatures (like "fi" as a single character).
This causes all kinds of problems (e.g. spellchecking).
Is there a way to turn ligatures off?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such package. It should be possible to implement by setting `interprogram-paste-function` to a function that calls the original function and do some replace-in-string magic on whatever is returned. It's easier to get started if you base your code on an existing package -- e.g. https://github.com/Lindydancer/highlight2clipboard (Its main task is to change how Emacs *export* text, but it also overrides the paste function.)